# Internal API calls and communication between NextJS app and express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) app with a [custom express server](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-server-and-routing). My `pages/index.js` is making an internal call to my express route `/api/users`. This is done using `isomorphic-unfetch` inside `getinitialprops()` like this:

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users');
```

My custom express server on top of NextJS has API routes that send back JSON data. Like so:

```
//some code before
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
let apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes.js');

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.use('/api', apiRoutes);

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

//more code
```

**So my question is,** is this the way to communicate between the my client side code and server side code? If so:

- How do I protect these endpoints so that the user doesn't just type in myNextJSwebsite.com/api/users and get a JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pattern to separate between api & renderer.

In order to secure your api end-point you will need to implement some kind of authorization, there is common lib for auturization in express, called [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/), you can check the types, it supports most of the common methods.

I personally prefer the [JWT way](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/), because it allows to work with many instances of my server due to the fact that there are no user session on the server.